# Autocomplete from directory in Fortran

Tags: input, autocomplete, fortran, intel-fortran, fortran95

I have a little program written in Fortran which needs to read in a file. 
The filename is provided by the user during runtime.

Now I want to emulate the bash behavior by autocompleting the filename, or cycle through available files by pressing [tab].

Since this will be only an extra bonus, and I don't have much time, I don't want to put a lot of time in such a feature.

So is there may be an Ifort feature or such doing this automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any such feature in libraries provided by Ifort.

You may try [GNU Readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline), but it may not have the exact features you need and beware it is licensed as GPL.

Edit: There are some equivalents with less restrictive licenses. For example, [Editline](http://www.s11n.net/editline/).