# How to print in the same position in fortran

Tags: fortran

Is it possible to replace a character in terminal with another character by changing format of print command or at least clear a line in terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in standard Fortran. Perhaps try using the [GNU Readline library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline). Related: [Autocomplete from directory in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335771/autocomplete-from-directory-in-fortran)

If you do not use the Windows terminal you can use the [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). For example, this first prints the stars, than moves back to the same line and writes "test" over the stars:

```
  print *, "***********"
  print *,achar(27)//"[2A"
  print *,"test"
end
```

Tested on a Linux terminal, will not work in the basic Windows terminal.